# Autoit Add data instead of replace data

Tags: autoit

I start a server with:

```
$BungeeServer = Run("java -Xmx512M -jar " & '"' & $file0 & "\BungeeCord.jar" & '"', $file0, $Hide, $STDERR_MERGED)
```

Then I  get the data from the server with(It's in a while loop):

```
Assign("sOutput", StdoutRead($BungeeServer, False, False) & @CRLF)
GUICtrlSetData($Edit1, $sOutput)
```

The problem is that It only returns the latest string of information. I need it to add instead of replace the values. Anybody know an easy way to do that?

Edit: When a server starts, you normally get a cmd window. I want to be able to have it in a Gui instead. Also I only want it to appear when I click a button, still it should start getting data when the server starts. The lines of text also went outside the box. I tried:

```
Do
$msg1 = GUIGetMsg()
    $line1 = StdoutRead($BungeeServer, True)
    $totalOutput1 &= $line1 & @CRLF
    GUICtrlSetData($Edit1, $totalOutput1)
    $line2 = StdoutRead($1, True)
    $totalOutput2 &= $line2 & @CRLF
    GUICtrlSetData($Edit2, $totalOutput2)
    $line3 = StdoutRead($2, True)
    $totalOutput3 &= $line3 & @CRLF
Until $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
```

The edit boxes were made with:

```
        $Form2 = GUICreate("Servers", @DesktopWidth - 15, @DesktopHeight - _GetTaskBarHeight() - 35, -1, -1)
        $Edit1 = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 0, 0, 634, 334, BitOR($ES_AUTOVSCROLL, $ES_AUTOHSCROLL, $ES_READONLY, $ES_WANTRETURN, $WS_VSCROLL))
        Font()
        $Edit2 = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 635, 0, 634, 334, BitOR($ES_AUTOVSCROLL, $ES_AUTOHSCROLL, $ES_READONLY, $ES_WANTRETURN, $WS_VSCROLL))
        Font()
        $Edit3 = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 634 + 634, 0, 634, 334, BitOR($ES_AUTOVSCROLL, $ES_AUTOHSCROLL, $ES_READONLY, $ES_WANTRETURN, $WS_VSCROLL))
        Font()
        GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
```

Edit: I found a better way to do it where I made a child window and didn't need all the other stuff:

```
    $GUI = GUICreate("Consoles", 1020, 600, 1282, 300, BitOR($WS_MINIMIZEBOX, $WS_SYSMENU, $WS_CAPTION, $WS_CLIPCHILDREN, $WS_POPUP, $WS_POPUPWINDOW, $WS_GROUP, $WS_BORDER, $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS))
    If GUICtrlRead($Bungee) = 1 Then
    $BungeeServer = Run("java -Xmx512M -jar " & '"' & $file0 & "\BungeeCord.jar" & '"', $file0, $Hide)
    If Not ProcessWait($BungeeServer) = 0 Then
        WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe", "", "Bungee")
        WinSetTitle("C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\java.exe", "", "Bungee")
        Global $hwnd0 = WinGetHandle("Bungee")
    EndIf
EndIf


_WinAPI_SetWindowLong($hwnd0, $GWL_EXSTYLE, $WS_EX_MDICHILD)
_WinAPI_SetParent($hwnd0, $GUI)


WinMove($hwnd0, "", 0,   0,   340, 300)
```

Still need to find a way to use ControlSend to the child windows :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `StdoutRead($BungeeServer, True)`

```
StdoutRead ( process_id [, peek = false [, binary = false]] )
peek [optional] If true the function does not remove the read characters from the stream.
```

OR

Consider storing the previous data before getting the new one. Instead of assigning the new data to the variable, you can just add it.
eg.

```
$totalOutput &= $newOutput & @LF
```

About `StdoutRead`: In order to get all data, it must be called in a loop.

From the help file:

```
; Demonstrates StdoutRead()
#include <Constants.au3>

Local $foo = Run(@ComSpec & " /c dir foo.bar", @SystemDir, @SW_HIDE, $STDERR_CHILD + $STDOUT_CHILD)
Local $line
While 1
    $line = StdoutRead($foo)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    MsgBox(0, "STDOUT read:", $line)
WEnd

While 1
    $line = StderrRead($foo)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    MsgBox(0, "STDERR read:", $line)
WEnd

MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Exiting...")
```

Considering all above, `StdoutRead` should be used like this:

```
Local $sOutput

While 1
    $line = StdoutRead($foo, True)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    $sOutput = $line
WEnd
```

OR

```
Local $sOutput

While 1
    $line = StdoutRead($foo)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    $sOutput &= $line & @LF
WEnd
```